# Importing Data from Excel file to MSAccess formatting each column in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, import, formatting

I'm coding a system which import a excel file to a ms access database, but I would like to know if is possible format every column before import to the database.

For example:

EXCEL FILE (xls or xlsx): COLUMN A = DateTime; COLUMN B = Integer; COLUMN C = Char(25); COLUMN D = VARCHAR(255)...

I'm using this code right now but it's automatically.

```
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
strPathFile = strPath & strFile
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
strTable, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
strFile = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: If datatype of excel and access column is same (even if numbers stored as text) then you no need to format access column individually. It will automatically convert datatype.

Comment: Data will have to be formatted in Excel prior to import, but you still might end up with data conversion errors. Best way is to link the Excel file and import through a query where you can shape the data as you wish.

Comment: I've never tried this for an Excel file, but after a short search I found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.runsavedimportexport)  the `DoCmd.RunSavedImportExport` method. 
You make the import once, setting the desired data types for each column, then check to save the import specification, and run it , rather than a new Import task. 
Please be kind enough (kinder than I...), and post here the code and process, If it works.. TIA

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible and advisable to format the columns in excel before importing, so as to reduce risk of some data not been correctly imported.

1. Select the cells(s) you want to modify.
2. Click the drop-down arrow next to the Number Format command on the Home tab. The Number Formatting drop-down menu will appear.
3. Select the desired formatting option

formatting options in excel includes

A.ABC General

B. Number

C Currency

D Short date

E Long date

and some others.

You have to format the columns in excel manually, it can not be programmatically done from access